# Show push notification while calling

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, push-notification

I am having a problem to show push notification during native calling. As my tester said that `whatsapp` notifications appear while you are native calling or going to receive a call, but my app, when you are on calling screen it doesn't show push notification until you decline the call or end that call. After that the push comes and you can do whatever you want with that.

Can you people advice me that what's wrong with my app. As far as I know, if you are out of application and push comes then only the web server responsible for that or iOS handles the all. Can you suggest me what am I doing wrong? I mean to ask do I need to add something to `.plist` file or etc.

Any suggestion or advice appreciated.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question.  It isn't clear if you are referring to receiving a call in your app or receiving a telephone call. Are the push notifications for your app or are you referring to push notifications for other apps while your app is running? Perhaps you could list the events that are occurring in order and the order that you want the events to occur in

Comment: @Paulw11- When you are making native call from iPhone or receiving and push comes of your app, then it would display on calling screen or not?

Comment: I just sent myself a direct message in twitter.  The push notification came up straight away if I was not in a call or in a call. If the phone was ringing then push message was displayed after I answered the call.  If I was making an outbound call and the far end was ringing then the push notification was displayed immediately

Comment: So you want to do something outside of your application? This isn't possible at all to mess with things outside of your application. Your application works in a sandbox mode so it doesn't know of anything outside of your application. So no there is nothing you can do.

Comment: @Popeye- So I can't see notification when my phone ringing?

Comment: No what I am saying is that you can't change how the device handles push notifications from within your app, well you can't in the sense of telling it if I am on a phone call wait until I am done. However there might be something in the settings that you can change, but as for altering this within your app that is a no go.

Comment: @iEinstein Have you got solution ? please update.